# PHP SQL show data in group based on id order by time

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a table which contain act_id (primary key), trip_id, start_time, end_time and activity name.
I manage to show rows of data order by end time  using while loop. However, I like to group the data in alternate row such that if 1st row and 2nd row belong to the same trip id, it will be in a same div and if 3rd row is different trip id, it will be in another div.

Below is my css and codes:

**CSS**

```
.group {
    padding:6px;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom:13px;
    font-size:12px;
}

.group:nth-child(odd){
    background:#bab8b8;
}
.group:nth-child(even){
    background:#eae9e9;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT trip_id, start_time, end_time, activity_name, act_id FROM TRIP ORDER BY end_time";       
    $params = array();
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);


                                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {

                                    $tripid = $row[0];
                                    $starttime = $row[1]->format('H:i');
                                    $endtime = $row[2]->format('H:i');
                                    $activitytype = $row[3];
                                    $activityid = $row[4];

                                ?>      
                                    <div class="group">
                                        <b>TRIP ID: <?php echo $tripid; ?></b>
                                            <div class="datarows" id="datarows">
                                            <a class="curday" data-artid='<?php echo $activityid; ?>'>
                                            <div class="time"><?php echo $starttime." - ".$endtime; ?></div>
                                            <?php echo $activitytype; ?>
                                            </a>
                                            </div>                             
                                    </div>                              
                                <?php
                                }   
?>
```

**This is my current output:**

[image]

I wan to achieve this output. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to store and group the results in an array and print these results with another loop:

```
<?php
// Statement
$query = "
    SELECT trip_id, start_time, end_time, activity_name, act_id 
    FROM TRIP 
    ORDER BY end_time
";
$params = array();
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Fetch data
$results = array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    $tripid = $row[0];
    $starttime = $row[1]->format('H:i');
    $endtime = $row[2]->format('H:i');
    $activitytype = $row[3];
    $activityid = $row[4];
    $results[$tripid][] = array(
        "starttime"    => $starttime,
        "endtime"      => $endtime,
        "activitytype" => $activitytype,
        "activityid"   => $activityid
    );
}

// Output
foreach ($results as $tripid => $activities) {
    echo '<div class="group">';
    echo '<b>TRIP ID: '.$tripid.'</b>';
    foreach ($activities as $item) {
        echo '<div class="datarows" id="datarows">';
        echo '<a class="curday" data-artid='.$item['activityid'].'>';
        echo '<div class="time">'.$item['starttime'].' - '.$item['endtime'].'</div>';
        echo $item['activitytype'];
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}       
?>
```

Notes: This is more *readable* approach. For large amount of data, an approach based on single loop (`while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))`) with appropriate `ORDER BY` clause and flags for start and end for each group, is also an option.

Comment: Thank you. It's quite close to what i wanted but i managed to solved it myself.